# how to seprate single values from logging debug

Tags: python, logging

I want to extract values of volume and last price from the output into some other variable but I am unable to fetch them

Results are as follows

> DEBUG:root:[{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 24, 12, 23, 34), 'last_price': 90.35, 'oi_day_low': 37008, 'volume': 23308, 'sell_quantity': 6035, 'last_quantity': 2, 'change': -0.17126125628418445, 'oi': 43808, 'average_price': 90.3275363, 'ohlc': {'high': 90.43, 'close': 90.505, 'open': 90.3125, 'low': 90.28}

```
def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
# Callback to receive ticks.

logging.debug("{}".format(ticks))
```

Comment: You want to extract values from above dict `DEBUG:root:[{'timestamp': ...`?

Comment: @ThatBird Yes I want to extract from that only

Comment: @VibhorKarnawat but don't you have that dict available in your code in `ticks`? Why not just do `var = ticks[0]['volume']`? I don't get that question :/

Comment: @shmee thanks man that actually worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    # Callback to receive ticks. 
    logging.debug("{}".format(ticks))
    var = ticks[0]['volume']
    var1 = ticks [0] ['last_price']  
    print(var)
    print(var2)
```

By using this and it worked for me.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [Python's data structures](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html). What you have there in `ticks` is a basic list of dicts